# I'm trying to change infix to postfix in java, what is the problem?

Tags: java, postfix-notation

I want to convert infix to postfix with stack data structure.

In this code, I didn't consider the case of * and /.

---

**example input: 10 - ( 3 + 4 ) - 1**

correct output is: 10 3 4 + - 1 -

but my output is: 10 3 4 + 1 - -

---

And this is part of my code. I checked some part that I thought that is wrong.
operator is name of stack I made.

```
public String infix to (String infix) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    int result=0;
    arr = infix.split(" ");

    String  element = "";
    String postfix="";
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        element = arr[i];

        if(element.equals("+")||element.equals("-")) {
            operator.push(element);

        }

        else if(element.equals("(")) {
            operator.push(element);

        }
        else if(element.equals(")")) {

            //**As I think, this part might wrong**

            while((!operator.empty())||(!operator.peek().equals("("))){  
                postfix = postfix.concat(operator.pop());
                postfix = postfix.concat(" ");

                if(operator.peek().equals("(")) {
                    operator.pop(); 
                }
                break;
            }   

            }
        else if(isNum(element)){        
            postfix = postfix.concat(element);
            postfix = postfix.concat(" ");          
        }

    }
    while(!operator.empty()) {
        postfix = postfix.concat(operator.pop());
        postfix = postfix.concat(" ");
    }

    return postfix;
}


public static boolean isNum(String s) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

thank you all.

Comment: Change this **(!operator.empty())||(!operator.peek().equals("("))**  to **(!operator.empty()) && (!operator.peek().equals("("))**

Comment: @suvojit_007 Please don't write answers in comments. Write answers as answers.

Comment: @suvojit_007 still wrong..

Comment: @Sienna Can you post the entire code?

Comment: @suvojit_007 yes but this is the almost entire code.. haha

Answer (score 0):

Change this `(!operator.empty())||(!operator.peek().equals("("))` to `(!operator.empty()) && (!operator.peek().equals("("))`

```
while((!operator.empty()) && (!operator.peek().equals("("))){  
                postfix = postfix.concat(operator.pop());
                postfix = postfix.concat(" ");

                if( (!operator.empty()) && (!operator.peek().equals("("))) {
                    break; //invalid
                else
                   operator.pop(); 
                }

            }
```

Comment: @Sienna Are you getting the same result with the above code?